# Simple Regression Based on Matrix Table

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am provided the below:

| Fruit | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | $5.00 |
| Kiwi | $3.50 |
| Grape | $4.00 |
| Orange | $10.00 |

My data is below:

| Unique_ID | Fruit | Amount | Frequency | Total_Per_Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | Apple | 6 | 5 | $150 |
| A02 | Grape | 8 | 4 | $128 |
| A03 | Kiwi | 7 | 3 | $94.50 |
| A04 | Apple | 8 | 6 | $240 |
| A05 | Grape | 4 | 6 | $96 |
| A06 | Orange | 9 | 3 | $270 |
| A07 | Apple | 3 | 4 | $60 |
| A08 | Orange | 6 | 4 | $240 |
| A09 | Orange | 4 | 3 | $150 |
| A10 | Grape | 10 | 2 | $80 |
| A011 | Apple | 10 | 4 | $200 |

My Code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor


df = pd.read_excel(path)
fruit_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.fruit)
freq_dummies = pdf.get_dummies(df.frequency)

df = df.join(fruit_dummies)
df = df.join(freq_dummies )
df = df.drop(columns = ['fruit','frequency']

y_var = df['total_per_week']
df = df.drop(columns = ['total_per_week']

x_train, x_test, y_train , y_test = train_test_split(df, y_var, train_size = 0.70, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

The formula is straight forward Price of Fruit * Amount * Frequency. It should be linear in nature as the price scales with the amount and frequency purchased.

My R2 is .70 and the model seemingly can't predict something this simple. I also tried Random Forest as well and the results were better...but I'm at a loss at why my predicted results are so off....

Comment: Whats your sample size/data frame look like?

Comment: I only provided a snippet of the data but my original dataset has about 200+.

Comment: sorry why would a R2 of 0.7 indicate your model isn't working?

Comment: In my mind. The problem is super simple and it should be easily solved but the predicted values are way off

Answer (score 0):

Two items:

1. Check that you still have the Price/Amount/Frequency columns in your input dataframe, to make sure you didn't drop them.
2. Linear regression assumes that data follow the form `Ax + By + Cz`. It won't work for an equation of the form `x*y*z`, which is the form of your relationship.

Comment: The amount and frequency is still part of my input. I just created dummy variables and added it to my data. I've also used a nonlinear regression - random forest as well and it also didn't have a good prediction.